# Is it possible for an attacker to log keystrokes of a bluetooth or wireless keyboard

Tags: encryption, wireless, bluetooth

Bluetooth and wireless keyboards are sending keystrokes wirelessly. Could this mean that an attacker (or spy) can log the keystrokes by monitoring the wireless or Bluetooth radio waves (or whatever)?

Is there any encryption or something that stops them from doing this? Same also applies to Bluetooth headphones or speakers.

Comment: Does this answer your question: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26356/what-can-an-attacker-do-with-bluetooth-and-how-should-it-be-mitigated

Comment: There are a lot of hits when Googling "Bluetooth encryption". Like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth It would be helpful if you included what research you have done so that we don't end up repeating the research you have already performed.

Comment: possible yes: [Hacker builds wireless Microsoft keyboard keylogger disguised as USB wall charger](http://www.networkworld.com/article/2868663/microsoft-subnet/hacker-builds-wireless-microsoft-keyboard-keylogger-disguised-as-usb-wall-charger.html).

Comment: So maybe they should add some encryption to Bluetooth (maybe by the pairing code)

Comment: Not to forget https://www.mousejack.com/

Comment: @SuiciDoga you didn't read either of my links - Bluetooth is encrypted.

Comment: Also the link says that Bluetooth is safe.Those wireless keyboards aren't