# What kind of information gets shared while pairing a device using Bluetooth?

Tags: mobile, phone, bluetooth

I am using LGKp500 phone. My software version is KP500AT_V10h. Its a simple touch phone. It's not a smartphone. Now can anyone tell me, when Im pairing my phone with another phone using bluetooth (simple version), does my contacts and messages gets visible in the other person's phone? I mean does the other person gets to see all of my phone's contacts, messages?

I know about the permission part. And while pairing the device, it only asks "ACCEPT CONNECTION REQUEST FROM device_name? Yes/No", now if chosen "yes" then the device is paired up. No other permission is requested or asked for accessing my files.

The phone with which my phone is being paired up, is a Smartphone. But my phone is not a smartphone. Its an old phone.

Comment: Have you tried searching for a feature phone that you can try this with?

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have the reputation to comment or mark this question as a duplicate I'll provide you the information you require.

Adi has a wonderful answer to what I believe is your question (link below):

[What can an attacker do with Bluetooth and how should it be mitigated?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26356/what-can-an-attacker-do-with-bluetooth-and-how-should-it-be-mitigated)

Of which I believe only the

> "**What can an attacker do once a malicious device is paired with mine?**"

matters to you.

The answer to this is dependent on the device you're using and the Bluetooth  profiles (sort of like Bluetooth standards/protocols) it supports. I've provided a link of the various profiles and what they can be used for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#OBject_EXchange_.28OBEX.29

I wasn't able to find the profiles your phone supports, but I believe that if both phones support the same profiles they will be able to interact with each other using them.