# What are the dangerous use cases of Montreal's bluetooth based vehicle traffic detection logic?

Tags: privacy, bluetooth

TechCrunch reported Montreal's [plan to use bluetooth to beat traffic congestion](https://techcrunch.com/2016/12/19/heres-how-montreal-is-turning-to-bluetooth-to-address-traffic-congestion/).
While I like the intent to beat traffic, I was thinking that this can be used for much worse intentions.

- The same system can be used by government to see the travel patterns of individuals
- A malicious insider can leak traffic patterns to terrorists

Since we don't know the entire implementation of the city's system, we can't really analyze the risks in it. I was wondering in what other ways can just the bluetooth detection system be misused.

The general misuse of bluetooth is already covered in [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26356/what-can-an-attacker-do-with-bluetooth-and-how-should-it-be-mitigated?rq=1)

Comment: Google already does this with maps. Why not just buy their data..

Comment: @rolls I see your point. But in any case it's a bit risky. Dont you think?

Comment: Yes but no more so than the risk google is already exposing you to. Anyone who gets access to your google password has a reasonable chance of being able to access your daily location history for the past few years if you have left it enabled. I'd also argue there is no need for them to implement a new system when they could simple purchase the data from Google.